# Discrepancy between select and deselect cells in tableview

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview, xcode8

I am creating an app which involves the use of a `tableview`, when a cell is selected the qty value is times by the price and then that value is added or subtracted from the total sum, depending on weather the cell is being selected or deselected. However every time I `deselect` a cell the application crashes.

> I am encountering the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while
>   unwrapping an Optional value" I figure there is a discrepancy between
>   the two function but I cannot find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

**heres my code:**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = thistableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCellcanteen
    cell.qtyValueThing.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    let somevar = itemsarray[indexPath.row]
    aselect.append("\(somevar)")

    let somevar2 = pricearray[indexPath.row]
    aselect.append("\(somevar2)")

    let thisvarthe = pricearray2[indexPath.row]
    value = Int(cell.qtyValueThing.text!)!

    aselect.append("\(String(describing: value))")
    amountToSave = Double(Float(thisvarthe) * Float(value))
    totalvalue = Double(Double(amountToSave) + Double(totalvalue))

    let totalvaluerounded = String(format: "%.2f", totalvalue)

    Total.title = "$" + "\(totalvaluerounded)"

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = self.thistableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCellcanteen
    cell.qtyValueThing.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let somevar3 = itemsarray[indexPath.row]

    if aselect.contains(somevar3){

        let intToRemove = aselect.index(of: somevar3)

        aselect.remove(at: intToRemove!)
    }

    let somevar5 = pricearray[indexPath.row]

    if aselect.contains(somevar5){
        let intToRemove = aselect.index(of: somevar5)
        aselect.remove(at: intToRemove!)
    }

    let thisvar2 = pricearray2[indexPath.row]

    //error is occuring below
    value = Int(cell.qtyValueThing.text!)!
    //error is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value


    if aselect.contains(String(value)){
        let intToRemove = aselect.index(of: String(value))
        aselect.remove(at: intToRemove!)
    }

    amountToSave = Double(Float(thisvar2) * Float(String(describing: value))!)
    totalvalue = Double(Float(totalvalue) - Float(amountToSave))



    let totalvaluerounded = String(format: "%.2f", totalvalue)

    Total.title = "$" + "\(totalvaluerounded)"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and here it goes

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt   indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = thistableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCellcanteen
    cell.qtyValueThing.isUserInteractionEnabled = false


    if cell.qtyValueThing.text! != nil{
        if cell.qtyValueThing.text == ""{
            cell.qtyValueThing.resignFirstResponder()
            cell.qtyValueThing.text = "1"
        }
    let somevar = itemsarray[indexPath.row]
    aselect.append("\(somevar)")

    let somevar2 = pricearray[indexPath.row]
    aselect.append("\(somevar2)")

    let thisvarthe = pricearray2[indexPath.row]

    print(cell.qtyValueThing.text!)
    value = Double(cell.qtyValueThing.text!)!

    aselect.append("\(String(describing: value))")
    amountToSave = Double(Float(thisvarthe) * Float(value))
    totalvalue = Double(Double(amountToSave) + Double(totalvalue))

    let totalvaluerounded = String(format: "%.2f", totalvalue)

    Total.title = "$" + "\(totalvaluerounded)"
    }
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = self.thistableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCellcanteen

    if cell.qtyValueThing.text! != nil{
    let somevar3 = itemsarray[indexPath.row]

    if aselect.contains(somevar3){

        let intToRemove = aselect.index(of: somevar3)

        aselect.remove(at: intToRemove!)
    }

    let somevar5 = pricearray[indexPath.row]

    if aselect.contains(somevar5){
        let intToRemove = aselect.index(of: somevar5)
        aselect.remove(at: intToRemove!)
    }

    let thisvar2 = pricearray2[indexPath.row]




    //error is occuring below
    print(cell.qtyValueThing.text!)
    value = Double(cell.qtyValueThing.text!)!
    //error is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value


    if aselect.contains(String(value)){
        let intToRemove = aselect.index(of: String(value))
        aselect.remove(at: intToRemove!)
    }

    amountToSave = Double(Float(thisvar2) * Float(String(describing: value))!)
    totalvalue = Double(Float(totalvalue) - Float(amountToSave))



    let totalvaluerounded = String(format: "%.2f", totalvalue)

    Total.title = "$" + "\(totalvaluerounded)"

    cell.qtyValueThing.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

the key was making the *var non optional* and also checking if the object     *cell.qtyValueThing.text* Had a value